# Show specific dropdown when value is selected on Material ui TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have different components with Lists with different inputs in them.
I want to unable a set of list depending the value selected.

I'll give an example of what I'm trying to accomplish below the code:

```
const ControlInputs: React.FC = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const [calculation, setCalculation] = React.useState('')
  const [secondary, setSecondary] = React.useState(false); <--- attempted fail

  const handleCalculationChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{value: string}>
  ) => {
    setCalculation(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <List>
        <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemText primary="Control" />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>

        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem button className="control-inputs">
              <ListItemText primary="Calculation" />
              <FormControl variant="filled">
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
                  id="demo-simple-select-filled"
                  value={calculation}
                  onChange={handleCalculationChange}
                  label="Calculation"
                  aria-label="Drop down to select calculation input"
                >
                  <MenuItem value={0}>scf</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem 
                  control={secondary}
                  value={1}>relax</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={2}>vc-relax</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={3}>md</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={4}>vc-md</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
```

So if they select relax in the select under control I will need to add the items from ion and cell into the list.

My ion and cell components are in a different file.

Comment: What about this code doesn't do what you expect? Describe what's going wrong with it and maybe we can help you better.

Comment: @AlexWayne It doesnt fire the onchange function the way I need it. I dont know how else to implemented it also gives me an error saying that control is not a value. 
What I want to accomplish is that when the user selects the value "relax" under calculation dropdown, a new 2 dropdowns are shown which it would be my ions and cells dropdowns components that are located in a different file.

If "relax " is not selected then those dropdowns would be hiden. Does that makes sense?

Comment: What is "the way you need it"?  Maybe post a codesandbox link that demos the way it currently is being called.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wilson-5pwce?file=/src/App.tsx

So right know you can see 3 dropdowns with values nested in them. We have (control,iions and cells). 
Under the control dropdown theres a "calculation" option that gives the user different option values like: scf, relax, etc. 

I want the dropdown for Ions and cell to be hiden until the user chooses the relax value under control.

When a user selects the value "relax" the dropdown for ions and cells should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problems is that you seem to be trying to communicate across components, but those other components (`IonsInputs` and `CellInputs`) have no way of knowing what's going on inside `ControlInput`. One way to address this is have `ControlInput` notify its container (`App` in your example) if its calculation value changes (to "relax"), and then you can decide what to do with that (show or hide the other components).

Here's a simple example.  Code is also at https://codesandbox.io/s/young-river-ml251

**App.tsx**

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [relaxMode, setRelaxMode] = React.useState(false);
  const onControlCalculationValueChanged = (value: number) => {
    // "relax" has a value of 1
    setRelaxMode(value === 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Input Parameters</h1>
      <ControlInput onChange={onControlCalculationValueChanged} />
      {relaxMode ? <IonsInputs /> : null}
      {relaxMode ? <CellInputs /> : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

**ControlInputs.tsx**

```
interface ControlInputsProps {
  onChange: (value: number) => void;
}
const ControlInputs: React.FC<ControlInputsProps> = ({ onChange }) => {
  const handleCalculationChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: string }>
  ) => {
    setCalculation(event.target.value);

    // here's where you notify the container of the calc mode change
    onChange(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
  };
})
```